# Snapkit for android login

Tags: android, snapkit

I am using the Snapchat login for my android app. When I already have Snapchat installed on my device it opens up the app and asks me to give permissions as expected. When I give permission from Snapchat it is supposed to redirect me to my app from Snapchat, which is not happening and it gives an error saying "something went wrong. Please try again".

I am using just a dummy redirect URL i.e. "https//www.google.com". I have no server-side implementation so I am not sure what redirect URL I should use.

Thanks

Comment: I am having two pop-ups like "This website is trying to open another app". One is redirecting me to the playstore and another one is redirecting me to my installed app. Ideally, if I have an installed app then this should not happen. Can you please direct me for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in snapchat portal your app is in awaiting review state or rejected state...

[image: your image]

Answer (score 0):

This could have several reasons. My problem was that I had not yet uploaded an icon. The documentation is really bad...